# Getting rescheduling notic to specified appoitment

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

Maybe somebody knows how is linked a meeting (documment) with an rescheduled notice which are send after changing dates in meeting. I need do this in Lotus C API and C# api.

I need to check if after meeting was created did something change

Something like this

```
    var document = UserDb.GetDocumentByUNID(uniqId);
    if(document != null)
    {
       var col1 = document.GetResched(...)
       var col2 = document.GetInvit(...)
       .....
    }
```

Thanks

Marcin

Answer (score 1):

The UniversalID of the meeting is saved in the ApptUNID item on the reschedule notice.